# hosting company blocking google bots and crawlers

Tags: ip, google

I am having a site for the past three years and it is very active for the past two years. Until not the site is working well and also now but not after the hosting company blocked google bots.

Many pages appeared in the first page of the google search.

After they started blocking i couldn't see my links in the first page instead they appeared after 5 pages or they did not appear at all.

Will hosting companies be so stupid that they block and dont mention it to their users.

They want to protect themselves by making the websites at stake.

I display google ads and not this month i got only half for this 10 days.

I have made requests to other hosting companies like blue host and monster host that i wan to transfer my domain by making a condition that the will not block google bots which stops the business indirectly.

so any kind of help will be helpful.

how can i claim what i lost from the hosting company.

what other hosting companies consider the users (by informing the events like changing the IP or blocking google bot.)

It was really working hard to bring up my site but these people just crashed down my site in a few days.

:-(

Comment: I would say name and shame the company. Blocking search crawlers is a tad ridiculous!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first action you need to take is to contact your hosting provider- and explain the situation. It would be good to provide evidence to back up your case. I would suggest that you are probably not going to be able to claim what you have lost from the hosting company- as it's probably hidden in your contract with them that the hosting company will not be responsible for situations such as this.

How do you know it's your hosting company that has caused this situation? Google and other search engines change their algorithm regulary, and it's possible that one of these changes has affected your site/page ranking.

Comment: yeah i asked them and they said they are blocking ip's which are pinging their server very frequently. so i reduced the crawl rate in google webmaster tools. and then going to change the host. could you suggest some... the one i know for now is bluehost... but i want the one which has the cPanel control panel and not a custom built one.